# Голоса, отданные вами

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть у нас на сайте вкладка "голоса" в профиле участника. Выглядит она так:

> [image: Голоса]

Вот это "Голоса, отданные вами" меня как-то коробит. Всё ли тут нормально с точки зрения грамотной русской речи? Не стоит ли это как-то переформулировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сказать "отдать голос" (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/255499/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C). Возможно, еще не забыт лозунг: "Отдадим свои голоса за кандидатов Сталинского блока коммунистов и беспартийных!". Но у каждого – один голос. Один человек не может отдать свои **голоса**. Да и звучит все это как-то неуместно торжественно. Стоит как-то переформулировать. Например, вместо "голоса" написать "голосование", в подсказке написать: "Статистика вашего голосования";  подтемы: "за ответ", "против ответа", "за удаление", "за  восстановление", "за закрытие", "за переоткрытие" (чем оно отличается от восстановления?)

Вместо нынешних "голос 'за'" и "голос 'против'" можно написать либо "за ответ" и "против ответа", либо "понравилось" и "не понравилось".

Comment: Восстанавливается удаленное сообщение, переоткрывается закрытый вопрос.